# Hibernate - save is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using **@Transactional** instead of creating **TransactionManager** object and call. Can somebody give a reason why I am getting this **HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction** ?

**Bean** for sessionFactory and TransactionManager

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addUser(User user) {
        userDao.addUser(user);
    }
}
```

**UserDaoImpl.java**

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:348)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.save(Unknown Source)
at com.hemanths.expense.manager.hibernate.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.addUser(UserDaoImpl.java:19)
at com.hemanths.expense.manager.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.addUser(UserServiceImpl.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
```

Hibernate.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/emanager</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>

        <mapping class="com.hemanths.expense.manager.hibernate.entity.User"/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: have you activated `@Transactional` annotations by putting `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in your application context?

Comment: Do you have <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> in your spring config?

Comment: I am running a test. Do i need to annotate the test? like @ContextConfiguration in case of spring?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in HibernateTransactionManager to check if your program is entering the transactional AOP?

Comment: Do you have <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> in your spring config xml? If so, remove it.

Comment: @user3487063 Yes I have. I have uploaded hibernate configuration file. please check

Comment: remove that line and try.

Comment: Is wise have the `@Repository` with `@Transactional` too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

and try

Comment: could you please explain?

Comment: @Renju, read https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/context/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html, especially this line: In order for ensuring that happens, the sessions generated here are unusable until after Session.beginTransaction() has been called